# How to call action method before onClick event

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events, jsf-1.2

I got the trouble with this JSF. I like to call the action method first and then like to call the JavaScript OnClick Event.

```
<input value="Select" jsfc="ft:commandButton" style="width: 70px;" type="button" onclick="setReturnValues(this,'memId');" action="#{eem1001.EEM1001FormBean.memberChange(line.memId)}"/>
```

But JavaScript OnClick Event is call before action method.

How can I call action method before JavaScript OnClick Event.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can call action method on `mouseDown` event and  then on `mouseUp` event you can call your 2nd method `setReturnValues(this,'memId')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your desired method on body part. Like this

```
<body onload="methodName()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use JBoss Richfaces, you can add `a4j:support` to your button and with its `oncomplete` attribute you can call your javascript `setReturnValues(this,'memId')` after actual action  `eem1001.EEM1001FormBean.memberChange(line.memId)`
Like:

```
<input value="Select" jsfc="ft:commandButton" style="width: 70px;" type="button" >
  <a4j:support event="onclick" 
    action="#{eem1001.EEM1001FormBean.memberChange(line.memId)" 
    oncomplete="setReturnValues(this,'memId');"  
    disableDefault="true" />
</input>
```